# Create an array of random dates and values

Tags: jquery, date, random

I'm trying to create an array that looks like this:

```
([
    [Date.UTC(2003,8,24),8709],
    [Date.UTC(2006,8,25),872],
    [Date.UTC(2002,8,26),8714],
    [Date.UTC(2009,8,29),8638],
    [Date.UTC(2000,8,30),8567]
]);
```

---

I can create a random date, but I can't figure out how to add it to an array in that particular format. Here's some code, and a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nSRBC/1).

```
function randomDate(start, end) {
    return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()))
}

$(function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        var date = randomDate(new Date(2004, 0, 9), new Date());

        // instead of printing to a div, it'd save to an array
        $('#dates').append(date); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Update your fiddle with ur code

Comment: Print to file where exactly? Are you trying to send it to your server, or create files on the users computer?

Comment: Just to a txt file. The chart is currently created from a JSON request to a Highcharts sample data file.

Comment: To a text file where? The only thing you have access to is your own server, and that would require submitting something or sending an ajax request ?

Comment: I guess the data can just be added when the chart is created, instead of going to a file. Either way, I'm not sure how to create the array. And woops, Fiddle updated. Forgot to save.

Comment: Dont use alert in a loop of 1000 please use console.log

Comment: Changed to console.log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        var date = randomDate(new Date(2004, 0, 9), new Date());
        var randNum = Math.round(Math.random()*10000);
        arr.push([date, randNum]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks good, but how can I get it in the Date.UTC format above? Do I just have to pull out the day/month/year manually?

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript can not save to a local file, your best bet is to force the output to another window and let the user save it locally.

window.open("data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + "Your Date List"));

Comment: The question is not about saving the data but creating the data in the first place.

Comment: Do you want the printed date format in the array or can it just be a long?