# I want to be able to set a random date for my datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I have a date picker called `leave_start`, I would like the ability to set a min date that isn't static so a person could choose dates after the day they selected. How could I go about doing something like this and for some reason when I click on the future select box it doesn't reload date picker how could I fix that as well?

So when they select either yes or no for future select box. It will reformat the date picker accordingly.

So this is my view where the sick_day input would be the sick day text field would be the min date they would set.

```
=simple_form_for @entry, :url => url_for(:controller => 'entry', :action 

%td.lt= f.error :range_days, :class => 'er'

%table.table.table-bordered.table-striped{:style => 'table-layout:fixed; width:100% !important;'}

  %td.lt= f.text_field :sick_day, :id => 'sick_day', :placeholder => 'Optional Comment', :input_html => {:value => ''}
  %td.lt= f.error :indirect_id, :class => 'er'

%table.table.table-bordered.table-striped{:style => 'table-layout:fixed; width:100% !important;'}
  %th.lt
  %td.lt= f.input_field :future, :as => :select, :id => 'future', :label => false, :collection => ["YES", "NO"]
  %td.lt= f.error :future, :class => 'er'

%table.table.table-bordered.table-striped{:style => 'table-layout:fixed; width:100% !important;'}
  %th.lt Leave Start:
  %td.lt= f.text_field :leave_start,  :label => false, :id => 'leave_start', :input_html => {:value => ''}
  %td.lt= f.error :leave_start, :class => 'er'


%table.table.table-bordered.table-striped{:style => 'table-layout:fixed; width:100% !important;'}
= f.button :submit, "Submit", :class => 'customSub'
```

And here is my JavaScript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#future').click(function() {
       var selected = $(this).val();
       var new_day = $('#sick_day').val();
       if (selected == 'YES') {
          $('#leave_start').datepicker({minDate: new_day });
       }
       if (selected == 'NO') {
          $('#leave_start').datepicker({minDate: 0, beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends });
       } else {
       }
    });
  });
```

I tried this but got an error (TypeError: "#sick_day".val is not a function)

#### fixed this forgot the $ in front of var new_day = ('#sick_day').val();

Comment: Missing `$`.  `var new_day = $('#sick_day').val()` i guess!

Comment: `('#sick_day').val();` is not a function, but `$('#sick_day').val();` might well be.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897271/create-an-array-of-random-dates-and-values

Comment: Okay I fixed the function error, but for some reason when i click on NO or YES  for #future it doesn't redo the datepicker for the correct dates I have to refresh the page to see the effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After datepicker has been initialised the method to change the options is different [see API](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)

Need to add `"option"` before the changed value pair/array.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //create datepicker
    $('#leave_start').datepicker();

    $('#future').click(function() {
       var selected = $(this).val();
       var new_day = $('#sick_day').val();
       if (selected == 'YES') {
          $('#leave_start').datepicker("option", "minDate", new_day );
       } else if (selected == 'NO') {
          $('#leave_start').datepicker("option", {minDate: 0, beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends });
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this and now my datepicker isn't showing up. @Cobote

Comment: See my edit. My method does not create the datepicker. Your script is changing the options then creating the datepicker.